# How to workaround instaloader 429 too many requests

Tags: python

I've been using instaloader for months and it is perfect, just yesterday, I got this similar error:

```
Retrieving tagged posts for profile friendusername.
[  1] JSON Query to p/CCAJpexxxx/: 429 Too Many Requests [retrying; skip with ^C]
HTTP error code 429 was returned because too many queries occurred in
the last time. Please do not use Instagram in your browser or run
multiple instances of Instaloader in parallel.
The request will be retried in 660 seconds, at 11:25.
GraphQL requests:
  d6f4427fbe92d846298cf93df
    last 10 minutes: 1 requests
    last 11 minutes: 1 requests
    last 15 minutes: 1 requests
    last 20 minutes: 1 requests
    last 30 minutes: 1 requests
    last 60 minutes: 1 requests
  other
    last 10 minutes: 2 requests
    last 11 minutes: 2 requests
    last 15 minutes: 2 requests
    last 20 minutes: 2 requests
    last 30 minutes: 2 requests
    last 60 minutes: 2 requests
  iphone
    last 10 minutes: 1 requests
    last 11 minutes: 1 requests
    last 15 minutes: 1 requests
    last 20 minutes: 1 requests
    last 30 minutes: 1 requests
    last 60 minutes: 1 requests
  e31a871f7301132ceaab5650
    last 10 minutes: 1 requests
    last 11 minutes: 1 requests
    last 15 minutes: 1 requests
    last 20 minutes: 1 requests
    last 30 minutes: 1 requests
    last 60 minutes: 1 requests
^C[skipped by user]
Download <Post CCAJpexxxx> of friendusername/:tagged: JSON Query to p/CCAJpexxxx/: 429 Too Many Requests
[  2] 
Too many queries in the last time. Need to wait 656.5026688985527 seconds, until 11:25.
^C
Interrupted by user.
```

I haven't used it now for at least 4hrs. Any workaround for this one? Thanks.